# Is there a way to use voice biometrics to login to Windows 7?

Tags: voice, auto-login

I upgraded from Windows XP (where I used Microsoft Fingerprint reader), but Windows 7 doesn't have any drivers for that Microsoft Device so I am wondering if anyone has found a way to use voice recognition or voice biometrics to log onto a Windows 7 system. I don't want to have to use a program that uses a cell phone to remotely access the system, just something that will recognize my voice at the login screen and let me in.  I know that to use Microsoft Voice Recognition you already have to be logged into the computer, so that won't work.

Comment: Voice biometrics would be about as secure as a "swipe to unlock" screen. Anyone with a vaguely sensitive microphone in the same room could be able to unlock your machine. It would be worse than useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the helpful answers.  I ended up going with FastAccess face recognition.  It works well, and stores multiple recognized faces for you, with glasses, without glasses, etc. so it does a pretty neat job of recognizing. I couldn't fool it with a picture either. It works great.

Comment: Just curious -- say you had an accident and your face got all bruised and swollen.  How you would get into your computer?  Normal login still works?

Comment: I would just use the old fashioned fingers to type in the password in a case such as getting my face bruised and swollen. A failsafe in the face isn't recognized is to allow FastAccess to recognize your face as is, but you have to know the password to add a new face.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not natively support voice biometrics for login purposes, it is considered a security risk by Microsoft & as such (as you mentioned) the voice recognition software can only be launched once you are logged in to the operating system.

There are some services which you can use to customize your experience, such as:

[Voicevault.com](http://voicevault.com/)